# Nothing was returned from render error in React application when embedding a functional component and returning list from there

Tags: reactjs

I have the following component structure. But when I run the site I get **"Nothing was returned from render."** error.

Files:

**Layout.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./Layout.css";
import axios from "axios";
import Posts from "../../components/Posts/Posts";

class Layout extends Component {
  /**
   * Set a state
   */
  state = {
    posts: []
  };

  /**
   * Import data
   */
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts").then(response => {
      this.setState({ posts: response.data });
    });
  }

  /**
   * Render
   */
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="BlogContainer">
        <Posts postList={this.state.posts} />
        <div className="fullpost">
          <h1>Full Post (Name)</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Layout;
```

**Posts.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import Post from "./Post/Post";

const posts = props => {
  props.postList.map(post => {
    return (
      <div className="teasers">
        <h1>Recent Posts</h1>
        <Post title={post.title} content={post.body} key={post.id} />
      </div>
    );
  });
};

export default posts;
```

**Post.jsx**

```
import React from "react";

const post = props => {
  return (
    <div className="teaser" key={props.key}>
      <h3>{props.title}</h3>
      <p>{props.content}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default post;
```

Error message:

> posts(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a
>   return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.

From `Layout.jsx`.

However, when I remove `<Posts ... />` the error goes away.

If I run the `map` loop directly in `Layout.jsx` instead of embedding `<Posts />` functional component, everything works well - like the following:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="BlogContainer">
        <div className="teasers">
          {this.state.posts.map(post => {
            return (
              <div className="teaser" key={post.id}>
                <h3>{post.title}</h3>
                <p>{post.body}</p>
              </div>
            );
          })}
          ;
        </div>
        <div className="fullpost">
          <h1>Full Post (Name)</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

What went wrong in my approach?

Comment: your `Posts.jsx` should `props.postList.map(post => {`. BTW if you removed outer `{...}` there it would work because of implicit return. But because of `{....}` there you have to put `return` explicitly

Comment: Thank you for quick reply! Everything works fine now :)

Comment: nice. for some reason I've lost `return` part for `return props.postList.map(post => {`. So it's good you've finally fixed that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `return` in your posts component

Posts.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import Post from "./Post/Post";

const posts = props => {
  return props.postList.map(post => {
    return (
      <div className="teasers">
        <h1>Recent Posts</h1>
        <Post title={post.title} content={post.body} key={post.id} />
      </div>
    );
  });
};

export default posts;
```

or you could skip the `return` but also remove the wrapping `{}`

```
import React from "react";
import Post from "./Post/Post";

const posts = props => props.postList.map(post => (
      <div className="teasers">
        <h1>Recent Posts</h1>
        <Post title={post.title} content={post.body} key={post.id} />
      </div>
    ));

export default posts;
```

Comment: Thank you for quick reply! I have used the second approach is more logical since I am not doing any JS coding inside the component, just returning the JSX. Now everything works fine!